# Как создать нейронную сеть, которая предсказывает выходные данные на основе некоторых данных

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, анализ-данных

Есть 11000 строк данных, выглядят они так:

[image: InputData]

Столбец 1n-29n - это данные, полученные с КА в точке Lat Lon.

Столбец W-ncep-это значение, получаемое в зависимости от данных в столбцах 1n-29n.

Пожалуйста, помогите мне выбрать архитектуру нейронной сети, и если есть примеры решения таких задач в машинном обучении (я не смог найти их в Google) пожалуйста угостите ссылочкой.

Ссылка на исходные данные:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zOXjHv_cebfDI5Nk1qjiT2qdsxRn_f_r/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Могу добавить код выборки данных с помощью pandas и тд.., но это вроде для данного вопроса не нужно.

Comment: Какой именно столбец вы предсказываете - W-ncep?

Comment: А что значит «КА»?

Comment: Лучше добавьте хотя бы кусочек самих данных в текстовом виде. Ну или код, если с помощью кода можно получить откуда-то данные.

Comment: @MaxU КА - космический аппарат.

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, W_ncep

Comment: @CrazyElf добавил ссылку на данные.

Comment: @Denis В исходных данных столбцы кажется никак не обозначены. Где там что? Просто номера

Comment: @CrazyElf столбцы нужно использовать 1n-5n, они обозначены) в 1 строке

Comment: А, понял. А где W_ncep, учиться то как без целевой переменной? )  И  Lat, Lon?

Comment: Вы можете хотя бы вкратце описать суть данных?

Comment: @CrazyElf W_ncep там тоже есть столбец).

Comment: @Denis А, всё, нашёл )

Comment: @MaxU Есть спутниковый снимок (если брать в частном случае - точка). У точки есть координата, и значение с 5 каналов спутникового датчика. Есть программа рассчитывающая водозапас в каждой точке спутникового снимка, выдаёт эта программа W_ncep. Тобишь при значениях этих 5 каналов, она считает W_ncep.

Comment: А что измеряют датчики?

Comment: @MaxU температуру отраженную от поверхности.

Comment: Конкретизируйте заголовок вопроса. Почти любая нейросеть предсказывает выходные данные по входным (да и почти любая программа в принципе)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Зачем сразу нейросети? У вас обычные числовые данные, поэтому надо начинать с [линейной регрессии](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) и потом только переходить к более сложным моделям, если качество будет не устраивать. Да и то обычно больше помогает конструирование полезных для модели признаков на основе имеющихся данных, чем просто переход на более сложные модели. Сложные модели склонны к переобучению, особенно если данных немного. А 11000 сэмплов - это совсем не бигдата. Линейные модели зачастую хорошо работают и на миллионах строк данных.

Что касается дополнительных признаков, то в данном случае можно попробовать кластеризацию на широте и долготе с разным числом кластеров, это часто пробуют делать, когда есть данные по широте и долготе.

И да, временные ряды в данном случае совсем не к месту - у вас нет времени в данных. Временные ряды - это когда данные берутся в одних и тех же условиях, но в разные моменты времени и тогда надо учитывать развитие ситуации во времени, это другие подходы и модели.

Посмотрел ваши данные. Да, они совсем не линейные, придётся использовать сложные модели, вы были правы. Но не посмотрев предварительно на данные так говорить нельзя. Да и не факт, что и сложные модели справятся. Я попробовал [Random Forest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html), он хорошо учится на всём массиве данных, но плохо реагирует на [кросс-валидацию](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html), значит данные довольно разные в разных частях датасета. Видимо и правда нужно использовать кластеризацию, пробовать PCA и другие техники.

В общем, нужно дальше исследовать данные, к сожалению, сейчас у меня времени нет, если будет ещё актуально, могу вернуться к этому вопросу через пару дней.

[image: W_ncep]

[image: Lat]

[image: Lon]

[image: 1n]

[image: 2n]

[image: 3n]

[image: 4n]

[image: 5n]

В общем, если хорошо перемешать данные, то RF даёт очень даже неплохой скор на мой взгляд.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

df = pd.read_csv('NormalData.csv', sep=';', usecols=['W_ncep','Lat','Lon','1n','2n','3n','4n','5n'])

# перемешиваем строки данных на скорую руку
ind = df.index.values
np.random.shuffle(ind)
df = df.iloc[ind]

# готовим данные
X = df.drop(columns='W_ncep')
y = df['W_ncep']

# пробуем линейную регрессию
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
print(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y, reg.predict(X))))

# 5.29377282306937 - ну, не очень, да

# пробуем рандом форест
rf = RandomForestRegressor(100, n_jobs=-1)
rf.fit(X, y)
print(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y, rf.predict(X))))

# 0.10392955819342073 - отлично, но надо проверить кросс-валидацией

print(np.sqrt(np.negative(cross_val_score(rf, X, y, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', n_jobs=-1))))

# [0.29938888 0.32708244 0.29119675 0.33106258 0.33019189]

print(0.33/df['W_ncep'].mean())

# 0.011000052136926787 - т.е. ошибка порядка 1% в среднем, вроде неплохо
```

Код собственно простой нейросети на Keras, вход 6 нейронов, скрытый слой 5 нейронов, выходной слой 1 нейрон. Сходится довольно медленно, чуда не происходит. И это ещё без проверки кросс-валидацией, просто обучение:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='linear', input_dim=6))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X,y, batch_size=1, epochs=15, shuffle=False)
```

После 15 эпох MSE = 73.1349, если взять корень, это явно хуже, чем RMSE = 5 даже у линейной регрессии. И дальше сходится ну очень медленно, не думаю, что качество будет хорошее.

Если применить StandardScaler перед обучением нейросети, что обычно рекомендуется, качество становится ближе к качеству линейной регрессии: MSE = 30.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

ss = StandardScaler()
X = ss.fit_transform(X)
```

Comment: Согласен, 11000 сэмплов - маловато для нейросети.

Comment: Идея в том, чтобы получить максимальную точность, и выборка в 11 тысяч данных не конечная, всего их 46 тысяч

Comment: Ну можно сравнить решение линейной регрессии, и работу нейронной сети.

Comment: @Denis Нейросеть - это не всегда лучшее решение. Как по скорости (однозначно), так и по точности (it depends)

Comment: @Denis Не можно, а нужно. Начинать надо всегда с простых моделей. Сначала "know your data", а потом уже от простых моделей к сложным. Сначала смотрят корреляции, строят всякие графики на данных, а потом уже пробуют всякое.

Comment: Спасибо, будет здорово если вы вернётесь) потому-что голову уже сломал себе)

Comment: @Denis А что вы уже пробовали? Пробовали кластеризацию, PCA? Возможно, нужно будет как-то разделить данные, например, по кластерам, и обучать отдельные модели на разные кластера. Данных правда станет совсем мало для каждой модели, но в каких-то случаях другие решения хуже

Comment: @CrazyElf провел небольшой анализ, и выяснил, что ошибочно было использовать 1n-5n. Нужно использовать данные с каналов 3n,7n,12n,13n,18n,9n - именно по этим каналам высокая чувствительность. Почитав в интернете статью про задачу восстановления водозапаса на облаках, сделал вывод, что наиболее меньшая ошибка, достигается при использовании НС, с 1 скрытым уровнем, состоящим из 5 нейронов.

Comment: @CrazyElf обновил вопрос.

Comment: @Denis Эээ, ну вот, а я уже по тем каналам неплохой результат получил )))

Comment: @CrazyElf ну мы можем попробовать все)

Comment: @Denis А Lat и Lon то можно использовать? Без них гораздо хуже результаты - видимо, деревянная модель благодаря им хорошо разделяет данные, а без них сами по себе датчики плоховато инфу дают, чуть не на порядок хуже результат. Но так то да, с этими датчиками чуть лучше результат, чем с 1-5

Comment: @CrazyElf можно, но в нейронной сети они не нужны.

Comment: @Denis Ладно, позже попробую на Keras набросать решение

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо.

Comment: Хммм, если проверять модель на тех же данных, на которых вы ее обучали то можно ошибку и до нуля довести :-D

Comment: @MaxU Поэтому я и проверяю **хороший** скор RF с помощью кросс-валидации - RF как сложная модель действительно может прекрасно "выучить" тренировочные данные. У LR же скор **плохой** даже на тренировочных данных, нет смысла его проверять кросс-валидацией, он нас уже не устраивает :)

Comment: @Denis Добавил пример нейросети на Keras